# Zonal Histogram - Python

Tags: python, zonal-statistics, histogram

My main goal is to get the percentage of vegetation cover of gardens. The figure below shows the gardens (orange borders) with vegetation and non-vegetation.

[image: Snapshot of used data:]

I want for each garden the percentage of vegetation cover (number of green pixels /total number pixels. This computation needs to be done in Python. In QGIS I found a tool called 'Zonal histogram' which can be used for this.

Do you know a Python way to achieve the same or maybe how I could create a QGIS script which can be called by Python and runs this QGIS tool with output from Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[rasterstats zonal_stats](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/) with `categorical=True`.

For example with pandas so you can manipulate the data as you like:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

lots = gpd.read_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/lots.shp')
raster = r'/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/S2_maxlik.tif'

zs = zonal_stats(vectors=lots['geometry'], raster=raster, categorical=True)
stats = pd.DataFrame(zs).fillna(0) #One column per raster category, and pixel count as value
stats_percentage = stats.apply(lambda x: round(x/x.sum()*100,1), axis=1) #From pixel count to percentage

#      2     4     1    3     0
#0  99.6   0.4   0.0  0.0   0.0
#1  71.1  13.3   6.2  9.3   0.0
#2  37.8  34.2  28.0  0.0   0.0
#3  73.3   0.0   0.0  0.0  26.7

#Rename columns
stats_percentage = stats_percentage.rename(columns={0:'class_0',
                                                      1:'class_1',
                                                      2:'class_2',
                                                      3:'class_3',
                                                      4:'class_4'}, errors="raise")

#Merge(=join) the results back to your input
results = pd.merge(left=lots, right=stats_percentage, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
results = results.reindex(sorted(results.columns), axis=1) #Sort columns by name
results.to_file(r'/home/bera/Desktop/lots_with_stats.shp')
```

[image]