# Extracting values of pixels of multiple rasters using shapefile in Python

Tags: python, raster, shapefile

I have a set of rasters and a shapefile containing points. I need to extract the pixel values of each raster  (the points in the shapefile represents the pixels which I want to extract the value from]. These values I want to add to the attribute table of the shapefile (add it to the attribute based on the specific id). How can I do it in Python using cycles?

Comment: Using which python library? You need to add a code attempt or your question will likely get closed. Take a look at this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408583/zonal-histogram-python/408585#408585 . Do this for each raster and merge the results back to your dataframe/shapefile

Comment: Why write loads of python code when a single tool can do this? You don't state what GIS software you are using. If you have access to ArcMap use the [Extract Values to Points](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm).